# How to set the scroll position in a winforms combobox dropdown

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, autoscroll

I have several comboboxes in a UI each with a long list of similar entries (numbers). When the user selects an item from one of the comboboxes, I know the user will choose an entry with a similar value (but likely not the same) from the other comboboxes. Thus, after the user has selected a value, to help avoid forcing the user to do a lot of scrolling, I would like to "autoscroll" the next combobox dropdown to the vicinity of the last selected value (when this dropdown does not already have a selection). Ideally I would like the scroll position set such that the last selected value appears in the middle of the dropdown.

So far I have attempted to do this by setting the selected item in the dropdown event, but that has its own [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640438/detecting-user-selection-in-combobox-dropdownclosed-in-winforms). Is there a way to set the scroll position of the dropdown without having to select an item?

So far I have tried this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessageCb(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, out COMBOBOXINFO lp);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

// P/Invoke declarations
private struct COMBOBOXINFO
{
   public Int32 cbSize;
   public RECT rcItem, rcButton;
   public int buttonState;
   public IntPtr hwndCombo, hwndEdit, hwndList;
}

private struct RECT
{
   public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

private const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
private const int LVM_SCROLL = (LVM_FIRST + 20);

private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
private const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;
private const int SB_PAGEDOWN = 3;

private void comboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  COMBOBOXINFO info = new COMBOBOXINFO();
  info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
  SendMessageCb((sender as ComboBox).Handle, 0x164, IntPtr.Zero, out info); // seems to work
  SendMessage(info.hwndList, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero); // does nothing
  SendMessage(info.hwndList, LVM_SCROLL, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) 50); // does nothing         
}
```

However, that does not seem to work. The COMBOBOXINFO structure seems to be populated properly, but SendMessage WM_VSCROLL and LVM_SCROLL have no effect.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve completely, but why don't you just rearrange the select list so that the last select item appears   first? (or just have two copies of it - one on top an one an one where it is normally)

Comment: Because the user will likely choose a different item than the last selected item -- but that different item will be *close* to the last selected item. I have tried to select the last item, but like I say in the question that has its own problem (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640438/detecting-user-selection-in-combobox-dropdownclosed-in-winforms )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that sending a message with WM_VSCROLL, LVM_SCROLL (as well as calling SetScrollInfo()) do work for setting the scroll position of the ListView shown as a dropdown by a ComboBox; the issue is with the DropDown event, which gets raised before the ListView has actually been shown. I figured this out because GetScrollInfo() returns a min, max of 0 when called in the DropDown event. Setting a timer for a 1 second delay from when DropDown was fired and calling GetScrollInfo() after that delay returns a sensible min, max; setting the scroll position after that delay also works.

I am obviously not fond of the delay, but I don't think there is an event available for when the ListView has been shown? Is it possible to create some event?